# stuck in converting htacces to nginx rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx, server, rules

Tested some online converter for this but nothing works for me.

This is `.htaccess` code - please help me to get this one working.

```bash
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(auth|my_posts|upcoming|contact|panel|login|account|register|recover|logout|search|random_post|index|ajax).html$ $1.php [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^pages/([^\.]+)\.html$ page.php?prefix=$1 [QSA,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /error.php?code=404

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .* - [S=5]
RewriteRule ^users/?((index)\.html)?$ users_list.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^users/([0-9]+)/([^\.]+)\.html$ user_$2.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?((index)\.html)?$ catgory.php?prefix=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)\.html view.php?cat=$1&id=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^(sitemap|rss)\.xml $1.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap_([0-9]+)\.xml sitemap.php?sitemap=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^lang_pkgs\.js lang_pkgs.php [QSA,L]

AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm
```

**Edit:** Added 2 converted rules from 2 different online convertes. I have tested and both didnt work and gave me error 500.

```
rewrite ^/(auth|my_posts|upcoming|contact|panel|login|account|register|recover|logout|search|random_post|index|ajax).html$ /$1.php last;
    rewrite ^/pages/([^.]+).html$ /page.php?prefix=$1 last;
if (-f $request_filename){
    set $rule_2 1;
}
if (-d $request_filename){
    set $rule_2 1;
}
if ($rule_2 = "1"){
}
    rewrite ^/users/?((index).html)?$ /users_list.php last;
    rewrite ^/users/([0-9]+)/([^.]+).html$ /user_$2.php?id=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/([^/.]+)/?((index).html)?$ /catgory.php?prefix=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/([^.]+)/([^.]+).html /view.php?cat=$1&id=$2 last;
    rewrite ^/(sitemap|rss).xml /$1.php last;
    rewrite ^/sitemap_([0-9]+).xml /sitemap.php?sitemap=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/lang_pkgs.js /lang_pkgs.php last;

error_page 404 /error.php?code=404;
location /auth {
rewrite ^/(auth|my_posts|upcoming|contact|panel|login|account|register|recover|logout|search|random_post|index|ajax).html$ /$1.php break;
}
location /my_posts {
rewrite ^/(auth|my_posts|upcoming|contact|panel|login|account|register|recover|logout|search|random_post|index|ajax).html$ /$1.php break;
}
location /upcoming {
rewrite ^/(auth|my_posts|upcoming|contact|panel|login|account|register|recover|logout|search|random_post|index|ajax).html$ /$1.php break;
}
location /contact {
rewrite ^/(auth|my_posts|upcoming|contact|panel|login|account|register|recover|logout|search|random_post|index|ajax).html$ /$1.php break;
}
location /panel {
rewrite ^/(auth|my_posts|upcoming|contact|panel|login|account|register|recover|logout|search|random_post|index|ajax).html$ /$1.php break;
}
location /login {
rewrite ^/(auth|my_posts|upcoming|contact|panel|login|account|register|recover|logout|search|random_post|index|ajax).html$ /$1.php break;
}
location /account {
rewrite ^/(auth|my_posts|upcoming|contact|panel|login|account|register|recover|logout|search|random_post|index|ajax).html$ /$1.php break;
}
location /register {
rewrite ^/(auth|my_posts|upcoming|contact|panel|login|account|register|recover|logout|search|random_post|index|ajax).html$ /$1.php break;
}
location /recover {
rewrite ^/(auth|my_posts|upcoming|contact|panel|login|account|register|recover|logout|search|random_post|index|ajax).html$ /$1.php break;
}
location /logout {
rewrite ^/(auth|my_posts|upcoming|contact|panel|login|account|register|recover|logout|search|random_post|index|ajax).html$ /$1.php break;
}
location /search {
rewrite ^/(auth|my_posts|upcoming|contact|panel|login|account|register|recover|logout|search|random_post|index|ajax).html$ /$1.php break;
}
location /random_post {
rewrite ^/(auth|my_posts|upcoming|contact|panel|login|account|register|recover|logout|search|random_post|index|ajax).html$ /$1.php break;
}
location /index {
rewrite ^/(auth|my_posts|upcoming|contact|panel|login|account|register|recover|logout|search|random_post|index|ajax).html$ /$1.php break;
}
location /ajax {
rewrite ^/(auth|my_posts|upcoming|contact|panel|login|account|register|recover|logout|search|random_post|index|ajax).html$ /$1.php break;
}
location /pages {
rewrite ^/pages/([^\.]+)\.html$ /page.php?prefix=$1 break;
}
location / {
if (-e $request_filename){
rewrite ^/users/?((index)\.html)?$ /users_list.php break;
}
rewrite ^/([^/\.]+)/?((index)\.html)?$ /catgory.php?prefix=$1 break;
rewrite ^/([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)\.html /view.php?cat=$1&id=$2 break;
}
location /users {
rewrite ^/users/([0-9]+)/([^\.]+)\.html$ /user_$2.php?id=$1 break;
}
location /sitemap {
rewrite ^/(sitemap|rss)\.xml /$1.php break;
}
location /rss {
rewrite ^/(sitemap|rss)\.xml /$1.php break;
}
location /sitemap_ {
rewrite ^/sitemap_([0-9]+)\.xml /sitemap.php?sitemap=$1 break;
}
location /lang_pkgs {
rewrite ^/lang_pkgs\.js /lang_pkgs.php break;
}
```

Comment: Please share the nginx configuration(s) you have tried, and please sepcify *exactly* what the problem is - *nothing works* is very vague.

Comment: tested this one: http://pastebin.com/J4eBGbsS

Comment: and this one http://pastebin.com/pXfaGUVL

Comment: Ive an error 500 - if u need more details, pls tell me

Comment: Add the nginx configuration you have tried to your post instead of linking to them in the comments: links tend to become outdated.